# Platform independent Code fro C/C++/java without additional package

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, multiplatform, platform-independent

Is it possible to to make server/client code in C/C++/Java, that can be platform independent?

It should not require any additional package (like No JVM requirement) installation on system just the executable file to run (if possible on Windows/Linux/Mac).

If not could you tell me any other way (maybe language) to achieve this ?
Thank You

Comment: possible with Java Only

Comment: @cyberworm but Java requires JVM installation how can I accomplish it without the need of installing JVM on that machine.

Comment: in c++ there is QT framework which allows you to write almost platform independent, but im not sure if it needs any packages for the end user

Comment: Take a look at [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/examples-network.html). You'd be building on each platform using static linking. P.S. You cannot have _same_ executable running on each platform. That's not what "cross-platform" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just the executable file to run (if possible on Windows/Linux/Mac).

This can be done with Qt C++ by writing portable code and using static linking to bind the DLL's. A downside to this is that you will end up with a much larger executable file. Java uses the JVM which rules it out like you stated.

It should be noted that the platform you compile it for will be the only target the executable works on. So a program compiled on Windows won't work on Ubuntu (you will need to compile a seperate version for that - Unless you install the .exe in Wine perhaps).

Comment: can you tell me how large it might become because I want to make a thin client.
and  the compilation will have to be done even after static binding ?

Comment: @user1575044 This is a matter of how much code you will have and the amount of dependencies you have. I can't give exact numbers but it should be around 3-10mb for a small interface application. And yes you set up the static linking and then compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: NO! (As noted: If you do not want to compile for each platform independently)

Either you need platform targeted code or need a middleware like JVM with Java Bytecode or .NET Framework with MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language).
I guess node.js could be regarde as a middleware as well.

Since .NET Framework is not available in linux/mac I suggest using Java.

If you use static binding in C++ and Qt or whatever it is like adding the middleware to your binary. Still I suggest using an existing and wide spread middleware: Java.

Comment: What about static linking and Qt?

Comment: will Wrappers like Launch4j OR exe4j do the job.

Comment: I don't think it's a proper answer. There might be 3rd party libraries (even not such monsters as Qt), that are cross-platform and provide the needed functionality.

Comment: @Martin and if I compile C program on different OS like on Windows then the formed .exe will work on all Windows ?

Comment: It should work on all MS Windows, usually exe built on older window must be compatible with newer versions